# List of List of array of floats to an array of floats in Java

Tags: java, arrays, collections, buffer

I'm looking for an elegant way to convert a `List<List<float[]>>` to just `float[]` by flattening. I thought it would be a breeze but apparently I was wrong. I can't use Java 8 or external libraries to solve the problem. I also don't know the sizes of the inner lists and arrays, and they do not necessarily have the same size.

This is what I've got, I think it's way too complex for such a simple task:

```
private float[] toFloatBuffer(List<List<float[]>> buffers) {
    //First: creating a new list to store the Float values
    List<Float> mergedList = new ArrayList<>();
    //Adding the float values to the mergedList
    for(List<float[]> secondBuffer : buffers) {
        for(float[] b : secondBuffer) {
            for(float f : b) {
                mergedList.add(f);
            }
        }
    }
    //Creating the final buffer with the size of mergedList
    float[] merged = new float[mergedList.size()];
    //This doesn't work for some odd reason...
    //float[] merged = mergedList.toArray(); 
    int i = 0;
    //Adding the values of mergedList to merged
    for(float f : mergedList) {
        merged[i++] = f;
    }
    return merged;
}
```

Edit: I forgot to say that the outer List is a LinkedList for some good reasons. Maybe that's important to know.

Comment: It's a bit complex, and not efficient.  However you can't reduce the complexity much, that nested `for` loop has to be there.  You've pretty much got it.

Comment: That's a pity, I think it's the most ugly code I wrote this year...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would do it, though I not sure it is prettier, it should be more efficient esp as it doesn't create any `Float` objects.

```
public static float[] flatten(List<List<float[]>> lists) {
    // get the total size.
    int size = 0;
    for (List<float[]> list : lists) 
        for (float[] floats : list) 
            size += floats.length;
    // create an array of the right size.
    float[] ret = new float[size];
    int i = 0;
    for (List<float[]> list : lists)
        for (float[] floats : list) {
            // bulk copy the array
            System.arraycopy(floats, 0, ret, i, floats.length);
            i += floats.length;
        }
    return ret;
}
```

This creates some Iterators, however Escape Analysis might place them on the stack to avoid garbage.

The following only creates one object

```
public static float[] flatten(List<List<float[]>> lists) {
    int size = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < lists.size(); i++) {
        List<float[]> list = lists.get(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
            float[] floats = list.get(j);
            size += floats.length;
        }
    }
    float[] ret = new float[size];
    int pos = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < lists.size(); i++) {
        List<float[]> list = lists.get(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
            float[] floats = list.get(j);
            System.arraycopy(floats, 0, ret, pos, floats.length);
            pos += floats.length;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

If you create a `List<Float>` you create at least one object per element.

Comment: Peter's second example is what I was thinking of.  Sometimes the ugly code is the correct code.

Comment: Thank you, this looks already better than my implementation. Honestly I lost you at the Escape analysis part. Can you give me a brief explanation why the second example is better than the first one?

Comment: Note that the OP later added that "the outer list is a LinkedList for some good reasons" so it's probably unwise to use indexed access on it. I doubt the reasons for LinkedList are good, but that's a different discussion. :-)

Comment: @WardVa when you iterate over a collection, this creates an Iterator object, unless Escape Analysis can determine the object doesn't escape the method and can be placed on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this elegant recursive example that you can adapt to your need:

https://gist.github.com/l-ray/11472207

As with any recursive algorithm, you should add some checks to avoid overflows if your lists are huge.